# Inter-process file locking in java that throws exception

Tags: java

I used FileChannel's tryLock method to obtain a lock on a file from two different java applications, (obviously spawned with 2 different PIDs) , and observed that when a lock is not available, trylock returns **null** instead of throwing an exception.

As per the javadocs :-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock--

FileChannel's trylock method should throw exception for inter-thread contention, but returns null for inter-process contention. 
Is there an API where i could get an exception for inter-process contention as well ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, the file lock being owned by another process was considered to be a common case, and not an exceptional situation requiring an exception to be thrown. [Lock.tryLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock()) doesn't throw an exception either, it returns false.

If you want to throw an exception in this case, you can do it yourself:

```
    FileLock fileLock = channel.tryLock();
    if (fileLock == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Lock already held by another process");
    }
```